# TF lite on andriod

Tags: android, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow-lite

I want to understand some points in this code which is used in tf lite app on andriod

### private fun convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteBuffer {

```
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Batch_SIZE * inputSize * inputSize * pixelSize)##
```

The batch_size = 4 why the batch_size is 4 bytes ?>> The tutor says because the datatypes for inputs and outputs of the exported model is float...but I can't understand how?...Also, he says 'when it comes to fully-intger pre-optmized model, the value turns out to be one'...again I don't understand anything. can someone help me and explain in details with examples?

I don't understand anything. can someone help me and explain in details with examples?
I don't understand anything. can someone help me and explain in details with examples?